# jquery preventDefault() not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

So the plan is to run ajax post when submit is clicked, but preventDefault() does not work, form gets submited. If i uncomment the ajax part it works again. Any ideas?

```
$("#submitformat").click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({    // if all this function is commented out preventDefault() works
url : "<?=base_url();?>aa.php",
type: "POST",
data : myArray,
success: alert('all good');
});
});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here `success: alert('all good');`.

Comment: ajax is called asynchronously so it wont wait for event.preventDefault() to execute.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); will prevent the submit of form via the button. Ajax will be executed normally. Since you have an error in your code, the script will not work and form will be submitted when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing error,

```
success: alert('all good');
```

and it should be

```
 success: function(){ alert('all good'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only cancel the `click` event. Not the `submit` event. You have to catch the submit event of your form.

```js
$('#idOfYourForm').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [onsubmit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event form jQuery.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
   <input type="text" name="one">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({    // if all this function is commented out preventDefault() works
url : "<?=base_url();?>aa.php",
type: "POST",
data : myArray,
success: function() {alert('all good')}
});
});
```

Comment: This will have the same result, as there is a syntax error in the code at `success: alert('all good');`.

Comment: Fixed it, but its not syntax error, because success gets the result of alert(), which is null;

Comment: sry not null, it's undefined

Comment: A **`;`** at the end of a `key : value` pair in an object literal is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use success function:

```
$("#submitformat").click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({    // if all this function is commented out preventDefault() works
url : "<?=base_url();?>aa.php",
type: "POST",
data : myArray,
success: function(){    
alert('all good');
}
});
});
```

Comment: That way `event.preventDefault();` is called at a time when the event could not be prevented anymore.